# json output in react-native with extra slash

Tags: php, json, api, react-native

Why does my API output displayed like this?

> [image]

I tested api in the POSTMAN and there was no problem.

I have no idea about where the slashes came from

Can anyone help me?!!!

Comment: it's not a problem . backslash is used for escape the double quotes.

Comment: @VinayakB No, it's different. If you look at the picture, you'll find that the backslash are added to output is extra
**"{\"data\"**

Comment: share the code.

Comment: @Amas
`async getzanjan() {
  let userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem("UserID");

  axios
   .get("Domain.com", {
    params: {
     data: 12,
     adminid: 1111111,
    },
    headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
   })
   .then(json => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(json.data));
    this.setState({ loading: false });
   })
   .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
   });
 }`

Comment: could ypu please console JSON.stringify(json.data) and paste here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The problem was because of the file that the code was written in

I rebuilt the .PHP file and the problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Its not slashes escape characters and alert requires string to render due to that if you set `JSON` also it will change to string as `JSON.stringify()`. Try to do `console.log(JSON.parse(response))`. You will get actual `JSON`.

Comment: Because of the extra slashes inside the output, There is no possibility to use Json.Parse and an error is given: "json parse error"  
I've used a `JSON.stringify()`  to see what I get

Comment: How did you call api??Can you share me the code, Is it axios or fetch??

Comment: thanks for reply, problem fixed with rebuilt the .PHP file